# Yii - human readable url in pagination

Tags: php, yii, pagination

I have added some UrlManager rules so that pages like

`/category/view?id=1`

now look like

`/1/cell-phones/`

but, the problem is that the `CGridView pagination` still looks ugly

`/category/view?id=1&page=2`

How can I change it to look something like this?

`/1/cell-phones/page/2`

Should I change/override createUrl method of the CController, or there is a better way?

my rule for the page that has pagination is

```
'<id:\d+>/<title>' => 'category/view/id/<id>',
```

and complete set tof rules is

```
'<id:\d+>/<title>/*' => 'category/view/id/<id>',
'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
'/<id:\d+>/<title1>/<title2>' => 'product/view/id/<id>',
'/<id:\d+>/<title1>/<title2>/<p_action:\w+>' => 'product/view/id/<id>/render/<p_action>',
'/<id:\d+>/<title1>/<title2>/<p_action:\w+>/parent_comment_id/<parent_comment_id:\d+>' =>      'product/view/id/<id>/render/<p_action>/parent_comment_id/<parent_comment_id>',
```

Answer (score 1):

Say you have used the following route configurations -

```
'<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<module>/<controller>/view',
```

So the URL's formed looks like - `/category/view?id=1&page=2`

Now try by adding `/*` to allow any further query string to beautify.

Modified -

```
'<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>/*'=>'<module>/<controller>/view',
```

Please check the `/*` added after `...<id:\d+>` to make it `<id:\d+>/*`

It should do the trick.

Comment: thanks, but it did not help, url stays the same, I updated the question to show the rule I use, maybe it will help...

Comment: Append `/*` for all the rules. It should work. I have tested it before answering here.

Comment: added /* to ALL the rules, and it worked partially, now the pagination url looks like this category/1/title/cell-phones/page/2, but i need to get rid of "title" and "cagegory" parts... my goal is /1/cell-phones/page/2, +1 for helping me advance though